# When using Arithmetic values Fetch a ProxyTypesAssembly must be used in order to know which types to cast values to

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

When arithmetic values in Fetch a ProxyTypesAssembly must be used in order to know which types to cast values to.

My Fetch XRML looks like:-

```
string fetchXml = string.Empty;
fetchXml = @"<fetch mapping='logical'>
<entity name='***'>
<all-attributes /> 
<filter> 
<condition attribute='****' operator='eq' value='067' />                                 
</filter>
</entity> 
</fetch>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you either can use a Proxy Class, or query the metadata to get the attribute types, or, since attribute types are immutable, if you know the type of the attribute when you're writing the code you can hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latebound, then you better use QueryExpression for your queries when obtaining this kind of error.